# How do I Compare two JSON files and form a new Custom JSON

Tags: python-2.7

## My first JSON file(json1.json)

```
json1 = [{
    "id": 547346726,
    "appname": "flipkart",
    "sum": 120,
    "hours": "1 day"
},{
    "id": 3094923,
    "appname": "Amazon",
    "sum": 40,
    "hours": "2 days"
}]
```

## My second JSON file(json2.json)

```
json2 = [{
    "id": 547346726,
    "Technology": ".Net",
    "deployed": "china",
    "Type": "Production"
}, {
     "id": 3094923,
    "Technology": "scala",
    "deployed": "Japan",
    "Type": "QA"
},
{
     "id": 123434,
    "Technology": "ruby",
    "deployed": "EU",
    "Type": "Business"
}
]
```

My JSON1 have two objects and my second JSON have three objects in that two objects ids are common. compare the JSON file with ids and form a new JSON. If there are no common objects id in two JSON files add the objects to Final JSON

## Expecting Output Final.json:

```
finaljson = [{
    "id": 547346726,
    "appname": "flipkart",
    "sum": 120,
    "hours": "1 day",
    "Technology": ".Net",
    "deployed": "china",
    "Type": "Production"

}, {

    "id": 3094923,
    "appname": "Amazon",
    "sum": 40,
    "hours": "2 days",
    "Technology": "scala",
    "deployed": "Japan",
    "Type": "QA"

},
{
     "id": 123434,
    "Technology": "ruby",
    "deployed": "EU",
    "Type": "Business"
}

]
```

## so far I tried this one

```
import json
a= json.load( open("newrelics.json"))
b = json.load( open("CareOrchestrator.json"))



    # Creating dicts by Ids.
d_a = dict( [ ( x["id"], x ) for x in a ] )
d_b = dict( [ ( x["id"], x ) for x in b ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a dict. 
You could try something like this:

```
import json

print("Hello World")


json1 = """[{
    "id": 547346726,
    "appname": "flipkart",
    "sum": 120,
    "hours": "1 day"
},{
    "id": 3094923,
    "appname": "Amazon",
    "sum": 40,
    "hours": "2 days"
}]"""

json2 = """[{
    "id": 547346726,
    "Technology": ".Net",
    "deployed": "china",
    "Type": "Production"
}, {
     "id": 3094923,
    "Technology": "scala",
    "deployed": "Japan",
    "Type": "QA"
},
{
     "id": 123434,
    "Technology": "ruby",
    "deployed": "EU",
    "Type": "Business"
}
]"""

a = json.loads(json1)
b = json.loads(json2)

final = []

for element in b:
    isThere = False
    for element2 in a:
        if element['id'] == element2["id"]:
            element2.update(element)
            final.append(element2)
            isThere = True
    if not isThere:
        final.append(element)

json = json.dumps(final)
```

Be aware that this solution just takes all the elements from the collection b. You won't have elements in the final result if they are just in the collection a. Therefore you'd need another loop or something like that.

Comment: In Case two ids are matched, then we should merge two objects as a single object and doesn't match append in a third JSON file.    Expecting output:                               finaljson=[{"id":547346726,"appname":"flipkart","sum":120,"hours":"1 day","Technology":".Net","deployed":"china","Type":"Production"},{"id":3094923,"appname":"Amazon","sum":40,"hours":"2 days","Technology":"scala","deployed":"Japan","Type":"QA"},{"id":123434,"Technology":"ruby","deployed":"EU","Type":"Business"}]

Comment: Sorry, I overread the merging part, I updated my answer. Hopefully it's somehow helpful to you.